# Rewrite URL'S with a question mark “?”

Tags: .htaccess

I have a few url that have appeared in google search console with "?" and under scores "_"in the URL. I have tried many ways to redirect them but i have failed. I believe it has some thing to do with using the `%{QUERY_STRING}`

this is the URL that i need redirecting from

```
repairs-blog?journal_blog_tag=iPhone
```

to

```
blog?journal_blog_tag=iPhone
```

Maybe someone could write the solution?

Comment: Any ideas how to rewrite the code

Comment: Searching in [tag:.htaccess] for [question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+question+mark) or [query string](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.htaccess%5D+query+string) already gives a lot of answers. Watch out for [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Thanks for your comments appreciated. I did search but i still cant rewrite to the correct URL? Thats why i asked for help here.

Answer (score 0):

When a query string is involved, you use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with `%{QUERY_STRING}`, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} journal_blog_tag=
```

and then rewrite with [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^repairs-blog$ /blog [L]
```

Because you don't change the query string, there's nothing more to do.
When you want to rewrite this URL, no matter what query string is given, you can also omit the `RewriteCond` and just use the `RewriteRule`.

---

If you want to redirect instead of rewrite, e.g. change the URL in the client, you add the [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteRule ^repairs-blog$ /blog [R,L]
```